# the router-link config's target do not generate to html code

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I config the Vue table header params like below:

```
render: (h, params) => {

      return h(
        'router-link',
        {
          props: {
            tag: 'a',
            target: '_blank',
            to: {
              name: 'physicalserverDetails',
              query: {id: params.row.id}
            },

          }
        },
        params.row.name
      )
    }
```

but when I check the generated html code, there did not generate the target param:

```
<a href="/physicalserverDetails?id=193" class="">CD-Z12</a>
```

is there anything I config wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal HTML attributes such as `target` must be passed inside an `attrs` object as stated in the [vue.js documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html). As `target` is passed as a `prop` in your snippet, it can't appear in the generated anchor tag.

Try the snippet below :

```
render: (h, params) => {
  return h(
    'router-link',
    {
      attrs: {
       target: '_blank'
      },
      props: {           
        to: {
          name: 'physicalserverDetails',
          query: {id: params.row.id}
        }
      }
    },
    params.row.name
  )
}
```